# How to connect Microstation V8i to Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, microstation, connection

I have been searching the web trying to find out if any one has connect Microstation to Postgresql, and to my surprise there has not been alot of chatter on ways to do this.. When looking at the database connection window in V8i I see no postgresql connection. Does anyone know a way to make this connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using Microstation v8i**

required:
[Postgres ODBC Driver installed]

only options are
ODBC
Oracle
OLEDB
BUDBC

[ODBC}
Open Microstation 
Settings>Database
Connect to Database
click search (magnifying glass)
Select Data Source
Machine Data Source
New> PostgresSQL35W (unicode) [Postgres Driver required]
environment/user/password settings

[image]

Postgres Connection Test successful.

See online documentation:
http://docs.bentley.com/en/MicroStation/hh_goto.htm#hh_toc.htm

Additional Information (after installing the Postgres driver)

Can be viewed in Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools >ODBC Data Source Administrator (Windows 7)

[image]

Comment: Great I have one question though if postgres is on a server do i have have to  have odbc driver installed on client machine as well? If so where do i have to put the dll in a certain folder for V8i to read it?

Comment: postgres odbc driver needs to be installed on the client machine. it will show up in the ODBC (Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools >ODBC Data Source Administrator (see new screenshot up in the answer)

Comment: Great got it! however just got off the phone with someone from Bentley and he said it is not possible for v8i to read in the geometry from postgres only tabular data....

Comment: Correct you need PostGIS to read geometry. This is not possible with v8i. Suggest you use QGIS which support PostGIS natively.

Comment: Your question clearly states 'PostgreSQL' not PostGIS.

Comment: Sorry yes about my syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Mapperz discovered, is possible to set up a WFS connection (if you have a WFS server) and consume it in Bentley Map (through Map Interoperability).

Comment: I did not discover anything it is the documentation http://docs.bentley.com/en/MicroStation/hh_goto.htm#hh_toc.htm Database Connections